# Proving that the absolute value of a polynomial can have arbitrarily large values

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am stuck in an exercise that asks me to prove that if

$a_n=c_0+c_1n+\ldots+c_pn^p$

then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert a_n\rvert=+\infty$.

I tried to approach it in this way:

$\lvert a_n \rvert \geq \lvert \lvert c_p \rvert n^p-\lvert c_0+c_1n+\ldots+c_{p-1}n^{p-1}\rvert \rvert$

but I don't know where to go next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $c_p \ne 0.$ Then we have

$$a_n=n^p(\frac{c_0}{n^p}+...+\frac{c_{p-1}}{n}+c_p).$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: And now I should prove that the expression between the parentheses converges to zero?

Comment: @Navid To zero... you'll have hard times if $c_p \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^p}=c_p$$

(so for any $\epsilon$, there is an $N$ such that...)